# How to increase the performance of spark in hpc (shared memory cluster)

Tags: apache-spark, shared-memory, hpc

I have been dealing with running spark on an hpc for a while. Due to my limited experience and knowledge I have stuck with a performance related issue.

First of all when i run my code in a server using 36 cores in local mode (

> .setMaster("local[*]")

), I got my results in 1 hr 30 mins. Now, I want to increase this by running my code in hpc. This hpc is a shared memory and as I was told that I do not need to set a yarn system or something else since all assigned cores will be able to employ the same cpu. To this end, I have prepared my jar file and invoke it by the bash file. My spark configuration is as below:

```
 val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("LSH-Cosine")
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")
      .set("spark.local.dir", "/local_scratch/tmp");
```

And my bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -l nodes=5:ppn=10
#PBS -l walltime=00:45:00
#PBS -l pmem=6gb


module load cerebro/2014a
module load Spark/1.4.1
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

spark-submit \
--class "com.soundcloud.lsh.MainCerebro" \
--master local[*] \
--executor-memory 256G \
--driver-memory 256g \
cosine-lsh.jar
```

So based on these settings, there will be 5 nodes each of which having 10 cores and in total 50 cores will be running. In addition each cores is assigned 6gb memory which is quite high. When I ran this code, I observed that about 100 gb is consumed and this resulted in no difference in temrs of performance compared to the server. then I have changed the  `#PBS -l nodes=5:ppn=10` to `#PBS -l nodes=10:ppn=10` and again I have observed  that about 100gb is consumed and no speed performance increasing.

So what should I do to exploit hpc to get my results in a more faster way?

Thanks in advance.